# how to fill image with gradient of 3 random colors?

Tags: c++, opencv, gradient, background-color, radial-gradients

I wonder how to fill openCV mat ( image ) with radial gradient of 3 random colors in 3 random positions with 3 random radii using openCV 2 API? Is it possible in one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is not the appropriate tool for that, because it's not a image manipulation library …

ImageMagick is a better for that job. Check out this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/ After you created the gradient image you can use it with OpenCV (whatever you want to accomplish).